# Transformar array vue em Json

Tags: json, vue.js

Estou tentando passar em uma `textarea` um array do Vue.js, e gostaria de transformá-lo em `json`, qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

```
new Vue({
    el:"#app",    
    data : {
      nome_da_variavel_array: 
          '[{variavel : 'valor'},{variavel : 'valor'},{variavel : 'valor'}]'
    }
}); 
<textarea>{{nome_da_variavel_array}}</textarea>
```

Comment: Tem algum código ou exemplo do que tu quer fazer?
Não entendi bem o que tu quer.

Comment: Editei na pergunta!

Comment: Seria mais fácil usar o método [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) e pegar um valor real e converter para JSON. Vou formular uma resposta com exemplo pra tu ver como é.

Answer (score 7):

Uma boa abordagem seria criar uma [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) que sempre retorna um objeto do `data` convertido para JSON.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    json: {
      teste: "Valor",
      um_array: [0, 1, 2, 99]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    json_string: function() {
      return JSON.stringify(this.json, null, '    ');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
    <textarea style="width: 100%; height: 150px;">{{ json_string }}</textarea>
</div>
```